# 404 - Resource not found showing in eclipse servlet

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, servlets

Hi I am new to servlet and jsp, if any mistake in my question please for give me.
Is it necessary to have a .java file to run any .html file on eclipse?

Comment: Please reword, what do you mean by 'run'?

Comment: It is best to avoid updating a question with additional questions unrelated to the original post.  That just creates confusion, especially as you will have old answers that now appear unrelated or incomplete.  Please put new/additional questions under a new question.

Comment: @chsbellboy , I removed the question thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will display an HTML file without any .java files in the same project.
Just right click your HTML file in eclipse and select `Open with -> Web Browser`.